# Error uploading a image file with type validation and save in folder and save path in database

Tags: php, image, validation

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","vfssite");


if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $filetemp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = $filepath . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $filepath = "uploads/galleryuploadwedding/".$filename;
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    move_uploaded_file($filetemp, $filepath);

    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) 
    {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO gallerywedding (imagename) values ('$filename')";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";
    } else 
    echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You expect someone to guess your error?

Comment: Am getting error. Notice: Undefined index: fileToUpload in C:\wamp64\www\downloaded\admin\galleryuploadwedding.php on line 12

Comment: You are getting "error" string because your last sentence. Use mysqli_error() function to get a possible error on the query execution.

Determine the error message and update your question.

Comment: Am new to PHP. Can you please help me with code modification ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yuva Kishore here is the code which work. It is similar to your code and you can differentiate here. I have user PHP MYSQLI PREPARED STATEMENT AGAINST SQL INJECTION WHEN YOU ARE SEND DATA WITH INPUT FIELDS.

HTML CODE :

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" >
</form>
```

PHP CODE TO UPLOAD IMAGE AND INSERT INTO DATABASE

```
 <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "admin";
    $dbname = "demo";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $filename_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        $path = 'uploads/galleryuploadwedding/';
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if($imageFileType == "jpg" || $imageFileType == "PNG" || $imageFileType == "jpeg"
        || $imageFileType == "gif") {

            //NOW MOVE UPLOADED FILE TO PATH
            if(move_uploaded_file($filename_tmp,$path.$file_name)){
                echo "Success";

                //NOW INSERT THE IMAGE NAME TO DATABASE
                //USER MYSQLI PREPARED STATEMENT AGAINST SQL INJECTION 
                $sql = $conn->stmt_init();

                $query = "INSERT INTO gallerywedding (imagename) VALUES (?)";

                if($sql->prepare($query)){
                    $sql->bind_param('s',$file_name);
                    if($sql->execute()){
                        echo "Successfuly inserted the image to database";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Error".$conn->error;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo $imageFileType."<br>";
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        }
    }
?>
```

### Feel free to ask questions comment below my post

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its Working Properly, you are really awesome.

Comment: @Yuva Kishore   if you like my answere kindly appriciate by clicking on TICK  mark just below  upvote.